# Getting error in run build in android with react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

> info Launching emulator...

> error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTwwt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have your android emulator is on, or your mobile is connected to the laptop and it has debugging mode enable

Answer (score 0):

make sure your device is connected and run `adb devices`

or

if you using simulator launch android studio or any simulator app
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXtto.jpg